# Integrate a multivariate function similar to a delta function

Tags: functions, numerical-integration, numerics, numerical-value

I am doing a code in Mathematica. I have the following function:

```
g[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_] := 1.665831200164505`*^11/((1 + (129.5` x1 - 64 x2)^4) (1 + (-64 x1 + 
     129.5` x2 - 64 x3)^4) (1 + (-64 x4 - 64 x2 + 
     129.5` x3)^4) (1 + (129.5` x4 - 64 x3 - 
     64 x5)^4) (1 + (-64 x4 + 129.5` x5 - 
     64 x6)^4) (1 + (-64 x5 + 129.5` x6 - 
     64 x7)^4) (1 + (-64 x6 + 129.5` x7)^4));
```

By a mathematical proof, I know for sure that its integral on $\mathbb{R}^7$ is $1$. However

```
NIntegrate[g[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7], {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x3, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x4, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x5, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x6, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x7, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* Output: 0.233274 *)
```

If I plot the function with respect to one $x_i$, I obtain something similar to a delta function:

```
Plot[g[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7] /. {x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 0, x5 -> 0, x6 -> 0, x7 -> 0}, {x1, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

So I decided to integrate on $[-1,1]^7$, since it seems that the function has its mass concentrated there:

```
NIntegrate[g[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7], {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 1}, {x4, -1, 1}, {x5, -1, 1}, {x6, -1, 1}, {x7, -1, 1}]

(* Output: 2.89057 *)
```

This is a very strange behaviour. Is there any technique to integrate functions that grow very quickly near 0, like a delta function?

Comment: You failed to mention that you get error messages: "NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small." This seems to give quite a bit of information about what is going wrong.

Comment: @bills If I increase WorkingPrecision, I obtain a wrong result as well: NIntegrate[
 g[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7], {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 
  1}, {x4, -1, 1}, {x5, -1, 1}, {x6, -1, 1}, {x7, -1, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20] (* Output: 4.7316 *)